# My friend is being held somewhere in New Zealand! Please help!

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

My friend ran into trouble when in New Zealand. He has been captured and is being moved around the country to a series of undisclosed locations. This is the last message I received from him.

```
My friend, I met a Kiwi, Kat
We hit it off, and that was that 

But thinking I was quite the wag
I mocked her motherland’s new flag

In hobbit prison now I rot
I need your help, it’s all I’ve got!

I hope this puzzle’s not a dud 
And fine ideas from you will flood…
```

Help me decipher the message, so I can retrace his steps. Where should I look for my friend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The last word of the first line of each paragraph refers to an IATA airport code in New Zealand:
> [KAT - Kaitaia Airport](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaitaia_Airport)
> [WAG - Wanganui Airport](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanganui_Airport)
> [ROT - Rotorua Regional Airport](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotorua_Regional_Airport)
> [DUD - Dunedin Airport](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunedin_Airport)
> If you are fast enough, he might still be at the last listed airport.

Comment: Just beat me to it!

Comment: You guys are fast :) I'll take that as a complete answer